# Get records from table 1 and join it from another table when the table 2 value does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

1st Table - explore_offers:

```
- id
- Primary Key - offer_unique
```

2nd Table - participated_explore_offers:

```
- id
- email - user_email
- Primary Key - offer_unique
```

What i want: 
* Show 1st Table records, and exclude those records, which are in the 2nd table with a specific email found

ex:

```
SELECT eo.*
     , peo.user_email 
  FROM explore_offers eo 
  LEFT 
  JOIN participated_explore_offers peo 
    ON eo.offer_unique = peo.offer_unique
 WHERE peo.user_email = 'test@gmail.com'
```

I've tried that example, and i'm getting 0 records. 
I have 2 records in the first table, and one in the second table, and the result i want is:

*. get that one record from the first table, where this record does NOT exist in the second table.

1st Table content:

```
Nr id  Primary Key
1  0   m1
2  1   m2
```

2nd Table Content

```
Nr id user_email      Primary Key
1  0  test@gmail.com  m1
1  0  test2@gmail.com  m2
```

Expected

```
Nr id Primary Key
1  1  m2
```

What i had:

0 Records

Comment: You have tried to explain, but it's much better to provide some sample data and expected output from that provided data.

Comment: Added the content and the expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbdd8/3)

Try this :

```
select * from explore_offers
where offer_unique not in 
(select offer_unique from participated_explore_offers where user_email='test@gmail.com')
```

Comment: It's correct, but not correct to my question. This query shows only records without any email, but i will have a lot of records with different emails, and i want the query to be specific for the selected email.

Comment: Please check the other questions's comment.

Comment: Answer of your serious question : I think the query i provided will have better performance. You can easily check it in your database if you have large dataset. You can also post a new question for this :)

Answer (score 1):

Move the email filteration to the `JOIN` condition to make it work with `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT eo.*,peo.user_email 
FROM explore_offers eo 
LEFT JOIN participated_explore_offers peo ON (eo.offer_unique = peo.offer_unique) 
                                          AND peo.user_email = 'test@gmail.com'
WHERE peo.user_email is null;
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6540ac/2):

```
| Nr | id | offer_unique | user_email |
|----|----|--------------|------------|
|  2 |  1 |           m2 |     (null) |
```

Comment: This query showed the records which had the email, i want to exclude it.

Comment: @Jaeger so you want those records that doesn't have the email `test@gmail.com`?? or what??

Comment: Yes, i want the records from 1st table, which does NOT contain that email from the 2nd table.

Comment: Please check the expected and table content which I've added.

Comment: @Jaeger - see my updated answer, it if fixed now, you can try the online demo,

Comment: Correct, a serious question: @Md. Suman Kabir which answer is better from a performance POV?