# mysql See what data is not in another table

Tags: mysql

This is my table

```
 table_datetime1
2018-03-01 00:05:00
2018-03-01 00:10:00
2018-03-01 00:15:00
2018-03-01 00:20:00
2018-03-01 00:25:00

table_datetime2

2018-03-01 00:05:00
2018-03-01 00:10:00
2018-03-01 00:15:00
2018-03-01 00:20:00
2018-03-01 00:30:00
```

in this case 2 records are not and I want to show me in the query those 2 records

```
example
2018-03-01 00:25:00
2018-03-01 00:30:00
```

Comment: Hint `LEFT JOIN .. ON... WHERE [table2].[column] IS NULL` or `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get records from table 1 and join it from another table when the table 2 value does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47994084/get-records-from-table-1-and-join-it-from-another-table-when-the-table-2-value-d)

Comment: And I do believe that your last question is the same as this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you both records:

```
select * from table1 a
left join table2 b on b.table_datetime2 = a.table_datetime1
where b.table_datetime2 is null
union
select * from table2 a
left join table1 b on b.table_datetime1 = a.table_datetime2
where b.table_datetime1 is null
```